# Sorting images by dates into a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I asked this before, but I'm still not sure why I just get an empty list when I test this

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
'''(dict) -> list of str

Given an image dictionary return a list of the filenames
sorted by date. 

>>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], \
'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.']}
>>> sorted_images(d)    
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
'''
new_list = []
for filename, (location, date, caption) in image_dict.items():
    if filename not in image_dict:
        new_list.append(filename)
return new_list
```

Comment: First of all, it's `items`, not `itmes`.. Anyway, `value_dict` seems to be a `list`, not a `dict`

Comment: Ok, how do I make my end result into a list and sort the images by date?

Comment: Because `image_dict` is a dict, keys are unique. In this case, You need only `new_list = image_dict.keys()`

Comment: Ok and where do I put that?

Comment: now it says too many variables to unpack

Answer (score 0):

Your list is empty because this condition is always false

```
if filename not in image_dict:
```

`filename` is a key in `image_dict`.

To get the output specified in the docstring, you can do something like this:

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):

    '''(dict) -> list of str

    Given an image dictionary return a list of the filenames
    sorted by date. 

    >>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], \
    'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.']}
    >>> sorted_images(d)    
    ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
    '''
    return [k for k, v in sorted(image_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])]
```

Comment: Ok so how can I fix this

Comment: `new_list = [k for k in image_dict]` maybe? I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to get my code to match the docstring, and make it work for the example in the docstring.