# Sorting filenames by date from a dict into a list of str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I asked this before, but I'm still not sure what it means when it says too many variables to unpack for this function when I test it. Can anyone please help me get my function to match what is required in the docstring?

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
    '''(dict) -> list of str

    Given an image dictionary return a list of the filenames
    sorted by date. 

    >>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], \
    'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.']}
    >>> sorted_images(d)    
    ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
    '''
    new_list = []
    new_list = image_dict.keys()
    for (filename, date) in new_list:
        if filename not in image_dict:
            new_list.append(filename)
    return new_list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting images by dates into a list from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205781/sorting-images-by-dates-into-a-list-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. The key to understanding the problem is that we are required to return a **sorted** list. For that, we typically use `sorted()`.

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
    '''(dict) -> list of str

    Given an image dictionary return a list of the filenames
    sorted by date. 

    >>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], \
    'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.']}
    >>> sorted_images(d)    
    ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
    '''
    return sorted(image_dict, key=lambda x: image_dict[x][1])
```

Notes:

- Passing a dictionary as the first arg to `sorted()` (or iterating a dictionary generally) returns a list of keys.
- The `key=` arg to sorted specifies the sort order. In this case, we sort according to the date field. `image_dict[x]` returns a list, `image_dict[x][1]` returns the date field.

If you are allergic to `lambda`, you can replace it with a named function, like so:

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
    '''docstring goes here'''
    def key_func(x):
        return image_dict[x][1]
    return sorted(image_dict, key=key_func)
```

And, if you are prohibited from using the `key=` argument to `sorted()` at all, you can take advantage of the fact that `tuple`s are sorted lexicographically. Construct a list of tuples that look like `(date, image_name)`, sort that list, then extract the image names. This is sometimes called the [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate) idiom.

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
    '''docstring'''

    date_name_list = [(v[1], k) for k,v in image_dict.items()]
    sorted_date_name_list = sorted(date_name_list)
    sorted_name_list = [item[1] for item in sorted_date_name_list]
    return sorted_name_list
```

Comment: Ok, but could we do this without lamda?

Comment: I mean can we use it just with the function provided?

Comment: def create_date_dict(image_dict):
    '''(dict) -> dict
    Given an image dictionary, return a new dictionary
    where the key is a date and the value  is a list
    of filenames of images taken on that date.
    
    >>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday']}
    >>> date_d = create_date_dict(d)
    >>> date_d == {'2017-11-03': ['image1.jpg']}
    True Here is a previous function. How could I call the current one with the previous one?

Comment: Off the top of my head, `date_dict = create_date_dict(image_dict)` / `return [filename for filenames in [date_dict[date] for date in sorted(date_dict)] for filename in filenames]`

Comment: Is that all in one line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but the reason you're getting that message is that you have `new_list = image_dict.keys()` but then are trying to unpack that with `for (filename, date) in new_list`. To fix, you would replace `image_dict.keys()` with `image_dict.items()`.

Comment: Ok I get this now dict_items([('image1.jpg', ['UTSC', '2017-11-03', 'Happy Friday']), ('image2.jpg', ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.'])]). How do I just get the filename sorted by date?